# Debug.Listeners for UWP apps

Tags: c#, debugging, uwp, win-universal-app

Is there any possibility to forward everything from `Debug.WriteLine` to a file in UWP app?

There is [`Debug.Listeners`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.listeners(v=vs.110).aspx) which is unfortunately not available in UWP apps.
However, I found NuGet package [`System.Diagnostics.TraceSource`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Diagnostics.TraceSource/) which enables to use `Trace` and `Trace.Listeners` in UWP. Therefore I would consider that it could be possible do it also with `Debug` but I did not find any suitable package or approach working in UWP.

Comment: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Logging-Sample-for-Windows-0b9dffd7

Comment: @RTDev I have seen that sample, but I do not want to go that way.

Comment: How about to write an own logger, which saves the debug message in a file and print it via Debug.WriteLine?

Comment: I concur with the custom logger.